# Squeezing/shrinking text horizontally

Tags: fonts, microtype

How can I 'squeeze' or 'shrink' some text horizontally? I've heard of the `microtype` package but I'm not familiar with its options. I tried playing around with it but I could only get it to shrink the text if it was just about to overflow the line. Is there a way to force-shrink a selected portion of the text?

Example - I have the following document and I want to be able to shrink/squeeze all or some porition of the text:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
This is a long line of text. This is a long line of text. This is a
long line of text. This is a long line of text. This is a long line
of text. This is a long line of text. This is a long line of text. 
This is a long line of text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can search for `scalebox` on this site's searchbar.

Comment: By shrinking are you referring to the inter-word/-character *space* or the actual *characters* as well?

Comment: @Werner I'd like to be able to adjust both, if possible. If I'm not mistaken, these can be adjusted with `\SetTracking` and `\SetExpansion` options using microtype but I just can't get it to work/enforce properly... sorry, I'm kind of a newbie.

Comment: @percusse Thank you for the suggestion but I'm having some difficulty getting `scalebox` to work properly when the text I'd like to squeeze is multi-line.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not getting the question right I guess. If you can include a MWE I'm sure our users will figure out a way. Just make up the smallest example starting from `\documentclass{...}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: @percusse Good point, I've edited the question with a small example. If I use `scalebox`, (e.g., with settings `\scalebox{0.8][1]`) then it works fine if the text if short enough to fit on one line. But with the example I've posted, the text falls off the page if I use `scalebox`.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but when I needed squeezed text I personally found it more visually appealing to just change the tracking (i.e., the inter-letter spacing, more or less) rather than to actually squeeze the individual letters.  My result was a combination of someone's forum reply (don't remember where), the `microtype` package documentation, and a lot of fiddling around to figure out how it actually worked.  I used this to make text more narrow in a table.  Here's my code, maybe it'll do for you.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}

%% Narrow letter spacing
\newcommand\narrowstyle{\SetTracking{encoding=*}{-50}\lsstyle}
%% Custom letter spacing
\newcommand\spacedstyle[1]{\SetTracking{encoding=*}{#1}\lsstyle}
%% Normal letter spacing
\newcommand\normalstyle{\SetTracking{encoding=*}{0}\lsstyle}

\begin{document}
This is a long line of text. This is a long line of text. This is a
long line of text. This is a long line of text. This is a long line
of text. This is a long line of text. This is a long line of text.
This is a long line of text.

% \narrowstyle as a shorthand for setting tracking to -50 --
% the result is quite squeezed
\narrowstyle
This is a long line of text. This is a long line of text. This is a
long line of text. This is a long line of text. This is a long line
of text. This is a long line of text. This is a long line of text.
This is a long line of text.

% \spacedstyle{} as a lets you set a custom value, e.g. -25
\spacedstyle{-25}
This is a long line of text. This is a long line of text. This is a
long line of text. This is a long line of text. This is a long line
of text. This is a long line of text. This is a long line of text.
This is a long line of text.

% ...and back to normal
\normalstyle
This is a long line of text. This is a long line of text. This is a
long line of text. This is a long line of text. This is a long line
of text. This is a long line of text. This is a long line of text.
This is a long line of text.
\end{document}
```