# Shrinking a font

Tags: fonts, scaling

I'm looking for a possibility to horizontally shrink the font I use in my whole document.

I do not only mean the tracking of the letters, but also (if possible) to reduce the letter width by lets say 2%.

PS:

I tried the tracking of the "microtype" package, but it didn't work for me, because I get tons of errors from my equations that won't compile any longer, as soon as I \usepackage[...]{micropage}. Without that, everything compiles fine.

```
! Extra \fi.
\MT@tr@outer@r@ ...er@next \relax \fi \fi \fi \fi 
                                                  \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \M...
l.35 ...rac{\epsilon_0\,k_B\,T_e}{\pi\,e^2\,n_e}}}
```

But tracking is anyway not really what I'm looking for, as I want to shrink the whole font...

Also I can't rely on special fonts that allow for specific options that would only work for that particular font...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's impossible to tell something unless you show the code you have.

Comment: Have you consulted the posting [Squeezing/shrinking text horizontally](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94805/5001)?

Comment: I have seen that, but it only uses microtype to change the letter tracking. This is _not_ shrinking a font character horizontally, as I like to have it.

Also a scalebox is of no help, because that would shrink also the formulas, figures etc. I have in my document. Especially it looks kind of wired, if I would put each page in a scalebox to get the font face a bit leaner... :-)

Comment: I haven't tested this, but with XeLaTeX, from `fontspec` [manual](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec): `\fontspec[Width=.98]{Skia}`

Comment: Is the transition from pdflatex (that I use currently) to XeLaTeX straight forward or will I have to change much due to incompatible packages?

Comment: @TeXchie: I don't know, but I remember seeing many questions like that on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Options:

- Use pdftex, get a Multiple Master font w/ a width axis --- set the width to what you want.
- create a virtual font which horizontally scales each character box
- load the font into FontForge, scale it horizontally to 0.98 size, install the modified font
- use a similar font which sets more economically
- design the entire document at 102.040816326530612% wider than it should be, post-process it to scale it horizontally to 98%

Comment: Thanks a lot, I feared that I would have to work on the font face.

The last option drops out, because that would also kill the aspect ration of my figures... The 2% were just an example, I would also like to do the same with 10%... :-)

Comment: Place the images horizontally enlarged to 102.040816326530612% and they become 100% when shrunk to 98% of their (horizontal) size.