# microtype Tracking warning

Tags: microtype

To save space in tables, I want to reduce the tracking in the words. To do this I am using code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95898/176762).

The code below works correctly and is displayed as expected, but for every occurence of \test I am getting a warning like this:
`` Package microtype Warning: tracking amount list `output.tex/8' will override list `default' for font `OT1////' on input line 8. ``
I wasn't able to figure out why this happens, maybe someone with deeper insight could help me out here.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newcommand\narrowstyle{\SetTracking{encoding=*}{-50}\lsstyle}
\newcommand{\test}{\narrowstyle Test}
\begin{document}
\test\test\test
\end{document}
```

Comment: So? It's just a warning. Since you do in on purpose, it's safe to ignore.

Comment: Yeah but I got a few thousand warnings it's really clogging up @Ingmar

Comment: Take a look at the `silence` package, then, It's very versatile.

Comment: `\SetTracking` is meant to be used in the preamble only. You could set up a `context` for the narrow parts: `\SetTracking[context=narrow]{encoding=*}{-50}`, and then in your `\narrowstyle` command: `\microtypecontext{tracking=narrow}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `\textls` instead, which works fine and without errors and doesn't require silencing any errors (though that is also a helpful option):

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\newcommand\narrowstyle[1]{\textls[-50]{#1}}
\newcommand{\test}{\narrowstyle{Test}}

\begin{document}
\test\test\test
\end{document}
```

Note that if you wanted to keep the original semantics, @Roberts answer is probably the best option:

```tex
\SetTracking[context=narrow]{encoding=*}{-50}
\newcommand\narrowstyle{\microtypecontext{tracking=narrow}}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're absolutely sure that the warning messages are innocuous, you could load the `microtype` package with the option `verbose=silent`.

Incidentally, I would replace

```
\newcommand{\test}{\narrowstyle Test}
```

with

```
\newcommand{\test}{{\narrowstyle Test}}
```

in order to limit the scope of `\narrowstyle`.

For more on this option, see section 3.5, entitled "Miscellaneous options" of the user guide of the `microtype` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[verbose=silent]{microtype}
\newcommand\narrowstyle{\SetTracking{encoding=*}{-50}\lsstyle}
\newcommand{\test}{{\narrowstyle Test}}

\begin{document}
\test\test\test --- looks dreadful

TestTestTest --- default
\end{document}
```