# How to compress or stretch text within a group use \usepackage{microtype}

Tags: luatex, microtype

I can do this for small text lines.
How can I do the same for a group?

MWE:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
%========================================
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
An example of compressing or stretching small text.

\textls[-15]{An example of compressing or stretching small text.}

\textls[15]{An example of compressing or stretching small text.}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

\begingroup
\lipsum[1-5]
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is no official interface but you could use `\def\MT@letterspace@{15}\lsstyle` inside the group

Comment: Thank you, @Robert. Here is the answer to my question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94805/squeezing-shrinking-text-horizontally